# Constructing a Gibbs sampler for Two component mixture model

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model

The usual two-component Normal mixture model is instructed in these slides [http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~rcs46/modern_bayes17/lecturesModernBayes17/lecture-8/08-data-augment.pdf](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/%7Ercs46/modern_bayes17/lecturesModernBayes17/lecture-8/08-data-augment.pdf).

We define Latent allocation variables $Z_i$. But how to implement the R code for full conditions of $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerous discussions on the Gibbs sampler for mixtures can be found on this forum:

- [Gibbs Sampling for Gaussian Mixtures](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/25088/7224)
- [Does Label Switching of Mixture model impact the inference of the whole mixture](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/495913/7224)
- [Conditional distribution in this Gaussian Mixture Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/384273/7224)
- [Bayesian mixture model joint posterior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/492126/7224)

R packages are available as well

- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sBIC/vignettes/GaussianMixtures.pdf
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mixtools/vignettes/mixtools.pdf
- https://rdrr.io/cran/ClusterR/man/GMM.html
- https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bayesm/index.html

Our book [Bayesian Essentials with R](https://amzn.to/3mjGCNA) (new edition of [Bayesian Core](https://amzn.to/3mjGCNA)) with Jean-Michel Marin contains a whole [chapter on mixture models](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4614-8687-9_6), with [R codes available on my webpage](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/%7Exian/BCS/index.html#Slides). The first edition of our [Monte Carlo Statistical Methods](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR) with George Casella also enjoys a full chapter on this topic.